# Landscape preview of android xml layout in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, screen-orientation

In Eclipse (ADT plugin) there is a neat feature to preview xml layout in graphical form. I set `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` for my `Activity` and I thought it would be shown in this way. But the preview seems locked to portrait orientation only. Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a bar along the top that lets you customise the preview. Device, orientation etc.

[image]

Comment: @Alex. Lol No worries. We all do it from time to time. Can we get an upvote here ? :p Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

in the menu above you have option to flip orientation, there you have landscape mode